# How to work with multiple checkboxes in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am pretty new in `mvc` basically i have `webform` background. so facing problem now to render and work with multiple `check box`.

i have developed my sample view model and now need bit help for render multiple `checkboxes`. one set of `checkboxes` for hobbies and one set of `checkboxes` for movies.

also want when user select `checkbox` then i want to show what are te `checkboxes` was checked in tabular format in same view.here pasting my sample view model code and expecting help. if anything need to modify in my `viewmodel` code then please do.

```
public class MyViewModel
    {
        public List<Movies> movies { get; set; }
        public List<Hobbies> hobbies { get; set; }
    }

    public class Movies
    {
        public int ID = 0;
        public string Name = string.Empty;
    }

    public class Hobbies
    {
        public int ID = 0;
        public string Name = string.Empty;
    }

  public ActionResult About()
        {
            var oVm = new MyViewModel
            {
                hobbies = new List<Hobbies>
                {
                    new Hobbies {ID=1,Name="Test1"},
                    new Hobbies {ID=2,Name="Test2"},
                    new Hobbies {ID=3,Name="Test3"},
                    new Hobbies {ID=4,Name="Test4"},
                    new Hobbies {ID=5,Name="Test5"}
                },

                movies = new List<Movies>
                {
                    new Movies {ID=1,Name="Test1"},
                    new Movies {ID=2,Name="Test2"},
                    new Movies {ID=3,Name="Test3"},
                    new Movies {ID=4,Name="Test4"},
                    new Movies {ID=5,Name="Test5"}
                }
            };

            return View();
        }
```

thanks

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to achive and what you find difficult about it? Post your view

Comment: hence i am new in MVC i am not being able to write code for view where i want to show 2 set of checkboxes for movies and hobbies. i want to use checkboxfor helper.........what will be the view code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not prety sure what you are tring to achieve here, but I can give a direction  to start. First, check out the Html extension method [`CheckBoxFor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.checkboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx).

As you can see from the description, it takes a `bool`, so you have to extend your classes to include a bool properties. `IsSelected` for example. I would implement the below sample `Movie` class:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }       
}
```

Then in your view you can iterate over your collection of moves and display a checkbox for every one like this:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Movies.Count; i++)
    {
        <div>Movie Name: @Model.Movies[i].Name @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model.Movies[i].IsSelected)</div>     
        <div>@Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Movies[i].Id)</div> //This will give you the id
    }

    <input type="submit" value="post" />
}
```

You can follow this approach with the `Hobby` class too if you want.
Here's what you get:

[image]

And here's the result after post:

[image]

Comment: i am working with list like this way `hobbies = new List<Hobbies>` so this code `@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model.Movies[i].IsSelected)` will work when action return VM which will have list....can we populate model ? i am asking bcause i am new in mvc?

Comment: from your picture why name is getting null when check is checked and form post?

Comment: "name is getting null" because it's not posted to the action. You can add it as a hidden input just like the id and it will be posted. You can populate your lists in your action and pass the MyViewModel object to your View like this: `return View(oVm);`

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you are asking for but I would start with something like:

```
    @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Chests.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.movies[i].Id)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.movies[i].Selected);
    }
```